# Is there infinitely many prime $p$ such that the normalized trace of Frobenius $\frac{a_p(E)}{2\sqrt{p}}$ is arbitrarily small (but not zero)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I just encountered the following problem and failed to find proper reference, could anyone kindly help to give me some illustration?

For an elliptic curve $E$ without complex multiplication (just like in the Sato-Tate conjecture), let $a_p(E)$ be the trace of Frobenius,  given an arbitrary small  positive number $\epsilon$, is there infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $|\frac{a_p(E)}{2\sqrt{p}}|<\epsilon$?

With the proof of Sato-Tate conjecture, the answer should certainly be yes, but what I am wondering is, without the result of Sato-Tate conjecture, do we still have that conclusion? If it is, could you kindly give me some reference? I already knew the supersingular case by Elkies theorem.

With many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to ask "is there infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $0<|\frac{a_p(E)}{2\sqrt{p}}|<\epsilon$", as in the title ?

Comment: @Watson Thanks Watson, certainly yes

Comment: This would also follow from the Lang–Trotter conjecture. So for example, the answer is "yes" for almost all elliptic curves, by work of David and Pappalardi.

Comment: Knowing that there are infinitely many supersingular primes ($a_p=0$) is enough. If the base field is $\mathbf{Q}$ (which seems implicit in the question), this is a famous result of Elkies.

Comment: @DenisChaperondeLauzières The question in the subject asks for non-zero values, and the question already mentions Elkies result. And the comment by Watson and response by the OP indicates he really want $a_p\ne0$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that the proof of such theorems do indeed require the full force of Sato-Tate. For example, if you take a general elliptic curve E defined over a number field $F$ which is not CM, then your problem is still open.